# Subtotal function not being evaluated by OLEDB

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, adodb

I have an excel spreadsheet I am accessing programmatically in C# using ADODB and the OLEDB api. I am attempting to retrieve the evaluated value of a subtotal function (`IMEX=1` is set in the connection string), but I only get values of 0 when it should be nonzero.

For example, `=SUBTOTAL(9, A1:A4)` will give me 0.

However, `=SUM(A1:A4)` gives the proper value.

I know I could work around this by using sum, but the spreadsheet is being provided to me using subtotal functions.